# An error occures when I try to add a basemap ''the underlying connection was closed an unexpected error occurred on a send''

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, basemap

When I try to add a basemap in ArcMap this massage appears to me

```
The underlying connection was closed an unexpected error occurred on a send
```

I use ArcMap 10.1

So, what should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: sounds like you require the ArcGIS Desktop TLS Patch https://support.esri.com/en/download/7666 but you have an older version so you need to look at https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000019328

Comment: I second @Mapperz, you are using a _very old_ version of ArcMap that is unsupported even by ESRI. You need to upgrade!

Comment: At some point, using ancient software is too risky to be sustainable. That point passed several years back for 10.1,  even if you applied every service pack and the scores of patches. You need new software.